# Removing new Line from sql record via Java

Tags: java, sql, regex

I am reading and manipulating a MS SQL table using JPA. I have text in the cells that I want to cleanup by removing line breaks. Below is one sample of the text (pasting this in notepad++ shows `**CR LF**` on each line) :

```
(
(NVSM in (1,2)) and
(NISFVSM in (1,2)) and
(TRMBVSM = 0)
)
```

I have tried the following code but I can not get rid of the newlines

```
flatTextString.trim()
        .replace(System.getProperty("line.separator"), " ")
        .replaceAll("\t", "")
        .replaceAll("(\\r|\\n)", "")
        .replaceAll("\\s{2,}", " ")
        ;
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Is there a reason to replace linebreaks with spaces? Maybe just `\R+` => `''` replacement is enough? Or `[\r\n]+` => `' '` if you need to replace 1 or more line breaks with a space?

Comment: If you mean "line.separator"), " " , yes it has to be so, because in other text cells it will make problem if i replace it whith ""

Comment: Shouldn't replaceAll("(\\r|\\n)", "") do that?

Comment: See [this demo](https://ideone.com/lVdz73), your code removes newlines. I added `flatTextString.replaceAll("[\r\n]+", " ")` and its output is the same.

Comment: how can I remove the space after opening and closing parenteses? I tried this: .replaceAll("\\( ", "(")
   .replaceAll("[ ]\\) ",
      ")")

Comment: So, you are asking now a different question or did you just fail to name the issue before :) ? I guess you need to remove space(s) after the opening and before the closing brackets: `.replaceAll("\\s+\\)", ")").replaceAll("\\(\\s+", "(")`. See [this demo](https://ideone.com/nqcgpb). The first output is with my code.

Comment: Shall I post that as an answer?

Comment: yes please, thanks a lot. I did not now how it works in comments :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest just replacing all newline and carriage returns with just a space, and then remove all whitespace before closing `)` and after opening `(`:

```
String flatTextString = "(\r\n(NVSM in (1,2)) and\r\n(NISFVSM in (1,2)) and\r\n(TRMBVSM = 0)\r\n)";
System.out.println(flatTextString.replaceAll("[\r\n]+", " ").replaceAll("\\s+\\)", ")").replaceAll("\\(\\s+", "(")); // My way
// => ((NVSM in (1,2)) and (NISFVSM in (1,2)) and (TRMBVSM = 0))
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/b0Ugyb)

As Java regex cannot use conditional replacement patterns, you can only chain `replaceAll` methods as I have shown in the code snippet above.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you.